# Как отобразить все элементы кроме первого

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Добавляю в приложение paper trail gem у него нулевой записью версии идет создание экземпляра модели

```
1   2018-04-10 19:07:38 UTC Alex    Update  Changes
0   2018-04-10 19:07:02 UTC Alex    Create  Changes
```

но мне необходимо чтобы отображались только изменения уже созданного экземпляра. Я думаю лучше всего сделать чтобы она не рендерилась во вьюхе

```
<% @ticket.versions.reverse.each do |version| %>
```

уверен, есть рубишный или рельсовый метод позволяющий сделать это максимально изыскано и просто, но никак не могу найти его

Answer (score 0):

Сделал так

```
<% @ticket.versions[1..-1].reverse.each do |version| %>
```

Comment: http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-drop